# Replace conditions with enum in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, react-typescript

Having the following original code, it is a function which based on the value of `toCheck` is building a css class:

```
const computeSomething = (toCheck: string) => {
   return clsx('flex', {
     'flex-start': toCheck === 'FIRST',
     'flex-end': toCheck === 'LAST'
   });
}
```

The requirement is to use `enum` for `toCheck`, tried something but probably it's wrong:

```
export enum toCheck {
  FIRST = 'FIRST',
  LAST = 'LAST'
}

const computeSomething = (toCheck: string) => {
   return clsx('flex', {
     'flex-start': toCheck.FIRST,
     'flex-end': toCheck.LAST
   });
}
```

The error says:

> Property 'FIRST' does not exist on type 'string'.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are not even using the parameter `toCheck: string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `toCheck` is not referring to the (intended) enum due to your parameter being named the same (`toCheck: string`). Changing the name of either should solve the problem:

```
export enum ToCheckEnum {
  FIRST = 'FIRST',
  LAST = 'LAST'
}

const computeSomething = (toCheck: string) => {
   return clsx('flex', {
     'flex-start': ToCheckEnum.FIRST,
     'flex-end': ToCheckEnum.LAST
   });
}
```

The convention is that enum/type should have Pascal case so I think this way is better.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you pass in toCheck as an argument? Just do this:

```
export enum ToCheckEnum {
  FIRST = 'FIRST',
  LAST = 'LAST'
}


const computeSomething = (toCheck: ToCheckEnum) => {
  return clsx('flex', {
    'flex-start': toCheck === ToCheckEnum.FIRST,
    'flex-end': toCheck === ToCheckEnum.LAST
  });
}
```

Comment: because I need to know which option to run

Answer (score 1):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the enum by using the same name for your parameter. Use a different name for the enum and the parameter to avoid it. The idiomatic case for enums is [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

After that, just use a generic that extends the enum type and you should have no problems:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=15&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtX0gGcAPeACgDorYBzQgLnjQGtUcB3VAbQF0BKRgDccWYAG4AUBJCpkAW3gAVHAGEAFuGbwA3hPjwAYgEkASgGVF8ALzwA5MfOLbAGj3wAMgEEL1u14suEgC+UmB4hBgEOHIADsgYIGbRIBhqWKg0vgA8liDECajAhPAYAJ4xIDiISqoaYMwAfGQYtZqMinzWDTpu8HAYyDD4RMRktogQeS49+rPjk8QAtBGwGLaMLeqaFA4WrrP683mLMsDrJa31FP6KvUF8kiESYbHxicmp6TRkylv1D-AAPSA+A4ZgSIA)

```ts
declare function clsx (...args: unknown[]): void;

enum ToCheck {
  FIRST = 'FIRST',
  LAST = 'LAST',
}

const computeSomething = <T extends typeof ToCheck>(toCheck: T) => {
   return clsx('flex', {
     'flex-start': toCheck.FIRST,
     'flex-end': toCheck.LAST
   });
}

computeSomething(ToCheck); // ok
```